# How to change schema name?

Tags: oracle, plsql, schema, oracle11gr2

I have created a user:

```sql
CREATE USER gds_map
IDENTIFIED BY gds_map;
```

And now I need to change a name. I tried to update or find other way but have not found nothing yet.

I will be glad of any hint.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't (at least not in a supported or vaguely responsible way).  You'd need to create a new user with the new username and drop the old user.

Answer (score 23):

***If you want to modify a schema's name,you should have the preveledegs on USER$***

**1. Get Id of a schema's name**

```
SQL> select user#,NAME from SYS.user$ WHERE NAME='TEST';
USER# NAME
---------- ------------------------------
*93* TEST
```

**2. modify the schema's name**

```
SQL> UPDATE USER$ SET NAME='NEW_SCHEMA_NAME' WHERE USER#=93;
```

**3. finished commit**

```
SQL> COMMIT;
```

**4. modify the system SCN**

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM CHECKPOINT;
```

**5.Then refresh shared_pool**

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;
```

**6. Modify the new schema's password**

```
SQL> ALTER USER new_schema  IDENTIFIED BY new_pass;
```

Comment: grateful to you, it saved my day, and worked like anything...thanks.

Comment: This method will update the schema name in objects (function, cursor, procedure and lob etc...) for oracle 11c . Is it best method  for rename the schema with objects ?

Comment: I do not recommend this method on 12.1. The database stores the old name of the schema somewhere else, except USER$. 1) The value in dba_context.schema remains old. 2) Packages and SQL-types in the renamed schema are not compiled. I get errors like: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kotaty805], [DATA_KOEF_TAB_REC], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Only DROP/CREATE helps.

Comment: The user$ table no longer exists

Comment: While this may work it should be noted that this is not a supported way to do this. Please check https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30020192108317

Answer (score 7):

No methods exists to rename an oracle schema.

Try,

1-Create new schema

2-Export the old schema,

```
$exp owner=test2
```

3-Import old schema to new schema,

```
$imp fromuser=test2 touser=newuser_name
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

1- login as sys

2- execute this:
     update sys.user$
     set name= 'new_name'
     where name = 'old_name';

3- then restart the database

Comment: You might want to watch for default tablespaces as well, so you don't start mixing objects

Comment: The user$ no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to do this so often that I even wrote an article about this topic

The workaround that I use is to "clone" the user to the same DB with a different name, using loopback dblink.

It's very fast and in the end, after a successful checkup, you can drop the old schema.

Check it here: http://www.dbarj.com.br/en/2014/11/rename-schema-oracle-11g-loopback-dblink/

Answer (score -5):

In oracle database you cannot rename your username but you can change your password.

```
alter user USER_NAME identified by <enter_new_password>;
```